# explain this confusing algebraic identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Can anyone show, step-by-step, how the expression on the LHS can be turned into the expression on the RHS?

$x^ay^b=a^ab^b(a+b)^{-(a+b)}(x+y)^{a+b}$

Comment: Seems to be false identity, could you recheck?

Comment: could you rewrite the expression? it doesn't seem right.

Comment: I doubt it can be done. Are you sure that you wrote the problem completely and without typos? This seems to be some sort of equation, not an identity.

Comment: this is exactly as it appears in the textbook! so either there's a mistake in the book, or it's just super complicated.

Comment: I didn't know how to type in the "identity" symbol here instead of the "equals" symbol, but the textbook gives this as an identity. How close can you guys get the LHS to something that vaguely resembles the RHS?

Comment: If the identity in the book is exactly as you wrote it, then there should have been some prose, before or after the identity, requiring some relationship between $x,y,a$, and $b$.  Otherwise, the identity is just wrong, as Juanito's answer shows.

Comment: I find it utterly bizarre and incomprehensible that you are asking for help with a problem **from a book** and you are not telling us **what book it is**. (It's as if I went to a car site to describe a problem I'm having with my car, but I refused to identify the make, model, or year of my car.) Is it that you think books are like snowflakes, and nobody else in the world has a book exactly like yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the numbers are positive, we in fact have
$$ x^a y^b \le a^a b^b (a+b)^{-(a+b)} (x+y)^{a+b} \tag{$\ast$} $$
with equality if and only if $x/y = a/b$.

This is a standard application of the AM/GM inequality, as follows:
\begin{align*}
&\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\cdot\frac{a+b}{a}\right)^{a/(a+b)}
\left(\frac{y}{x+y}\cdot\frac{a+b}{b}\right)^{b/(a+b)} \\
&\le \frac{a}{a+b}\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\cdot\frac{a+b}{a}\right)
+ \frac{b}{a+b} \left(\frac{y}{x+y}\cdot\frac{a+b}{b}\right) \\
&= 1
\end{align*}
Raising both sides to the power $a+b$ and rearranging yields ($\ast$), with equality iff
$$ \frac{x}{x+y}\cdot\frac{a+b}{a} = \frac{y}{x+y}\cdot\frac{a+b}{b} $$
which is equivalent to $\frac xy = \frac ab$.

Answer (score 1):

Take x=0, y=1, a=1, b=1. The LHS is not equal to RHS.
So, the identity is False.